# Converting mp4 files without frames into mp3 using python / moviepy

Tags: python, mp3, mp4, moviepy, pytube

So what I'm trying to do is convert the mp4 files I get from downloading YouTube videos with pytube to mp3 files using moviepy. However, those mp4 files do not contain any frames which raises `KeyError: 'video_fps'` in the ffmpeg_reader.

Is it even possible to do that with moviepy or do I need to use a different tool? I guess I could also just download the mp4 files with video but that would waste resources especially for large playlists.

---

Here is the code I used:

```
from moviepy.video.io.VideoFileClip import VideoFileClip
import pytube
    
def downloadPlaylist(url):
        playlist = pytube.Playlist(url)
    
        for video in playlist.videos:
            filename = video.streams.get_audio_only().download()
            clip = VideoFileClip(filename)
            clip.audio.write_audiofile(filename[:-4] + ".mp3")
            clip.close()
```

Comment: Try creating an AudioFileClip from the mp4 files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So just changing `VideoFileClip(filename)` to `AudioFileClip(filename)` was the solution:

```
    clip = AudioFileClip(filename)
    clip.write_audiofile(filename[:-4] + ".mp3")
    clip.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [ffmpeg-python](https://kkroening.github.io/ffmpeg-python/) package, which is a wrapper for calling [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/). For example (after installing with `pip install ffmpeg-python`), do:

```py
import ffmpeg
import pytube
    
def downloadPlaylist(url):
    playlist = pytube.Playlist(url)

    for video in playlist.videos:
        filename = video.streams.get_audio_only().download()

        _ = (
            ffmpeg
            .input(filename)
            .output(filename[:-4] + ".mp3")
            .run()
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Refrain from using `.get_audio_only()`
Try downloading the whole video with `.get_by_itag` or something similar.
Worked for me after getting the whole video.

Comment: As I said, that would unnecessarily take up time. @Tom Burrows answer worked for me.